# R emacs windows

Tags: windows, r, emacs

I'm a newbie, so bear with me. ive gone through instructions offered on Paul E. Johnson's site on using R and emacs on a windows platform. Ive downloaded both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of R 3.0.3 and Professor Goulet’s Emacs-ESS compilation. however when running gnu emacs, no R icon appears on the button bar. Moreoever, Ive tried right-clicking on an R file and tried opening it with runemacs.exe but that doesnt work. Windows refuses to display runemacs.exe as an option. R run on its own works fine though. Both R and Gnu emacs are stored in program files (not in program filesx86) if that helps. Also in the R folder there subfolders for both R 3.0.3 as well as R 3.0.0. Please help!

Comment: I don't know what the issue here is since I have never used R in emacs in an windows environment. And there is no clear way of answering a question. But if you are a newbie to R as you say, I would highly recommend you using RStudio instead of emacs. RStudio is an IDE for R and it has alot of functionality that can help you in the beginning of learning to use R.

Answer (score 1):

Have you started ESS from Emacs?

```
M-x R
```

Also, what is the path where you've installed R? That could be the issue and you likely need to edit a configuration file in Emacs. For example, in the `site-start.el` file.

```
;; Path to R executable. Uncomment and edit as needed if R is
;; installed in such an unusual place that ESS can't find it. (And
;; then keep updating with each R update!)
;(setq-default inferior-R-program-name
;              "c:/program files/r/r-2.7.1/bin/rterm.exe")
```

So you probably want to uncomment this and:

```
(setq-default inferior-R-program-name
              "c:/path/to/where/you/installed/r/r-3.0.3/bin/rterm.exe")
```

This is for the Goulet package and this configuration file is mentioned on the website.

EDITED: because I realized that I overlooked that you had used Goulet's package initially.